# How can I change th attribute rowspan using js

Tags: javascript, html

I have this tag:

```
<th id="empty-span" class="empty-span" colspan="15" rowspan="5">
```

and after I click on a button I want to have

```
<th id="empty-span" class="empty-span" colspan="15" rowspan="6">
```

how can I do it using js?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set colspan/rowspan for a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639561/set-colspan-rowspan-for-a-cell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply by getting the element then changing the rowSpan  proprety

```
document.getElementById("empty-span").rowSpan = "6";
```

Or with jquery :

```
$('#empty-span').attr('rowspan', '6');
```

Comment: Note that rowSpan isn't an attribute, it's a property.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
document.getElementById("empty-span").rowSpan = "6";
```

Or: with incremental :

```
var currentNode = document.getElementById("empty-span");
currentNode.rowSpan = parseInt(currentNode.rowSpan) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `rowSpan` using [`element.rowSpan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td).

To demonstrate, click on the first cell to change the `rowSpan` to `2`;

```js
function enlarge() {
  event.target.rowSpan = 2;
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td onclick='enlarge()'>Click me to enlarge!</td>
        <td>#1-1</td>
        <td>#1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>#2-1</td>
        <td>#2-2</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```